# Error: You must use startAt(String value), endAt(String value) or equalTo(String value) in combination with orderByKey()

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebaseui

I am using FirebaseRecyclerAdapter to display a list and I want to display only those keys which have the value true. (Note that the **value** of a key is stored as **boolean and not string**)

[image: Database Structure]

I tried using a query as follows:

```
mAdapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Boolean, PollAdapterViewHolder>(Boolean.class, R.layout.ongoing_poll_list, PollAdapterViewHolder.class, ref.orderByKey().equalTo(true)) {
            @Override
            public void populateViewHolder(final PollAdapterViewHolder pollViewHolder, Boolean model, int position) {...}
```

where,
`ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("subscriptions/" + FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid());`

However, I am getting this error:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: You must use startAt(String value), endAt(String value) or equalTo(String value) in combination with orderByKey(). Other type of values or using the version with 2 parameters is not supported
```

Is there any way to solve this problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like you're using equalTo(boolean).  The error message says to use equalTo(String).

I suspect that you don't actually want to use orderByKey().  It looks like you might want to use orderByValue() instead.

Comment: So the query should be ref.orderByValue().equalTo(true)?

Comment: I tried your solution and it's working! Thanks a lot!

Comment: I was useful to me too